# All Files Deleted While Uploading to GitHub?

Tags: git, github

I created a Mobile App using Visual Studio Code.
Now I am Uploading it on Github using Visual Studio(upload to GitHub extension)

But When I click on It. My Files were deleted I am not able to recover it .
I created that app in 2 weeks

I made that App using flutter
All files of android, gradle, main.dart is not deleted but the files

I created by myself is deleted. Including Icons,Images, All my .dart Files deleted

This Question Is not Written Well because I am fully depressed.

Comment: Have you installed git? If so, please run `git status`, `git branch - a` and `git log` in the terminal (inside the project directory) and post the output here (edit the question) . Note that this may be a problem with the extension. Were there any warnings when trying zo upload it to GitHub?

Comment: That feeling is well known by many of us. Fortunately, code always comes out better the second time written after data loss. However, it is unlikely that your files are gone, I suspect. The advice above is excellent. Maybe the extension stashed your code. Good luck.

Comment: try to check log,  branch, or stash.

Comment: I checked there. A messeage Appers no stash....

Comment: Note that if you didn't install git yet, it is a command-line tool available to download [here](https://git-scm.com/downloads).